# ASP.NET Core Razor pages web app on IIS - why can an object variable entered on one computer be viewed on another computer?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, iis, razor-pages

Ok so I am working with a very simple web app here and have a couple pages:

`orderform.cshtml`:

```
@page
@model mysite.Pages.orderformModel

@{
}

<form method="post">
    <div id="input-div" class="form-group mb-2 mt-2">
        <input id="firstname" class="form-control" />
        <input type="button" value="Next" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="Update()" />
    </div>
</form>

<div id="confirm-div" hidden></div>

<script>
    function Update() {
        document.getElementById('input-div').style.backgroundColor = 'green';

        var firstnamein = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
        var fileform = new FormData;

        fileform.append("firstnamein", firstnamein);

        $.ajax(
            {
                url: "./orderform?handler=Update",
                type: 'POST',
                data: fileform,
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN", $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                },
                success: function (Return) {
                }
            });

        document.getElementById('input-div').hidden = true;
        document.getElementById('confirm-div').hidden = false;

        $('#confirm-div').load('./orderview');
    }
</script>
```

`orderform.cshtml.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace mysite.Pages
{
    public class orderformModel : PageModel
    {
        public static string firstname {  get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostUpdateAsync(string firstnamein)
        {
            firstname = firstnamein;
            return Content("OK");
        }
    }
}
```

And `orderview.cshtml`:

```
@page
@{
    Layout = "_PlainLayout";
}

<div>
    Hello @orderformModel.firstname
</div>
```

So, when you go to the page `orderform` on one computer, and enter a name and click next, it will display "Hello 'firstname'".

If you then go to another computer and pull up the page `orderview`, it will show the name entered on the other computer. I need to know why it is this way. Why another person pulling the page up on another computer can view the data entered on the first computer. I am afraid I am missing some fundamental aspect of web apps on IIS server.

I always thought a new instance of the site and variables were created each time a computer or browser accessed the site but it seems that is not true. I hope someone can explain to me how this is. Hope you understand what I am asking!

I have tried using session variables thinking they may be unique to the browser session with the same result. I really wasn't planning on using session variable anyhow but did try that. Not sure what else to try. Just need clarification on why seemingly different instances or visits to the site on different computers share object or variable data.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What do you do in  your orderview.cshtml.cs ? I test your provided code, and I cannot get the display Hello 'firstname'.

Comment: Ok so orderview is just a razor view, no .cs.  I have made this as simple as i could to give example.  if you run the code as is, and go to orderform, enter a name or anything, click next it will put the entered name into firstname. and load the orderview in div and display hello 'firsname'.  I did just realize that the first time the orderview comes up 'firstname' is not displayed unless you refresh and go back.  But if you do this on one computer, then go to another computer and pull up orderview it will display what was entered on the other computer.  Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I didn't have time to test your code but I suppose the problem comes from declaring the property

```
public static string firstname { get; set; }
```

as **static** - it will always take the last entered valued.

Comment: Ok i understand that but my question then is in understanding how this works in say production on live server iis, when say two people are accessing the site at the same time this object will contain the last value entered for both people.  Like i said i thought the application on the iis server would create a new instance for each person but i guess it doesn't.  I am not sure how to deal with that.  I always thought when someone accessed a web app from iis that it would be a new instance isolated from others.  Now i realize that they are not.  Any thoughts?

Comment: it's just an instance running on server that's the key so you have a program running the page the users view are instances but the static variable it's just one hope this clarifies your doubts

Comment: @treigh55 Declaring the property as `static` essentially makes it a global variable. The solution is not to declare Razor Page properties as `static` unless you intend them to be global.

Comment: Ok now I understand thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Static fields of a non-static class is shared across all the instances. So, changes done by one instance would reflect in others.

Only one copy of a static member exists, regardless of how many instances of the class are created.

You can have a look at [Static Members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members#static-members) to know more.